# Which AWS Managed Policy includes permission to create EKS clusters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks

I am setting up a service (AWS IAM) account in AWS under which to run a Terraform script to build my infrastructure.

One of my resources is an EKS cluster, for which I need the permission `eks:CreateCluster`.  I am trying to find a single [AWS Managed Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html?shortFooter=true#aws-managed-policies) that includes this permission, because to my surprise the `AmazonEKSClusterPolicy` does not (and nor do any of the other `AmazonEKS*` policies I have found).  However, an exhaustive Google search reveals nothing.

I can add my IAM service user to the `Administrators` group - but that's more powerful than I want it to be.  I can create a custom policy that allows `eks:*` - but that seems unnecessary if there is already a Managed Policy that does this for me - is there?

Comment: In short, there isn’t a managed policy that you are looking for.

Comment: @MC_ - really?  Wow.  That's ... strange, given that it must be a fairly common task.  Oh well.

Comment: Yeah, I just attach Eks:* to the IAM role that deploys my cluster. And it is an in-line policy.

Answer (score 0):

As [marcincuber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275815/marcincuber) says, there isn't one; I did in fact create a custom policy that allows `eks:*`.